# Multiply 2d matrix with 3d array to get 4d array for component scores

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, pca

I have a matrix `seloas` of 4 people x 3 rotated components, and an array `seraw` of 5 items x 5 items x (the same) 4 people.
`seraw` are raw(ish) co-occurence counts, and `seloas` are (rotated) loadings from a PCA based on that `seraw`.
The slices (= matrices) of `seraw` are symmetrical (beacuse co-occurence counts).

```
seloas <- structure(c(-0.232535340320219, -0.230627299973683, 0.124356407389266, 
-0.0203386851625857, -0.12959177205967, -0.0872107254451076, 
0.349621793484575, -0.081476095636832, -0.180898736708137, -0.0310458270134685, 
0.115458426682197, -0.472159305850741), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
c("Willy", "Karen", "Kristina", "Stefan"), c("PC1", "PC2", 
"PC3")))

seraw <- structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.2, 
0, 0.2, 0, 1, 0.4, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0.0625, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0.166666666666667, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.111111111111111, 
0.111111111111111, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0.111111111111111, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0.111111111111111, 0, 1), .Dim = c(5L, 5L, 4L), .Dimnames = structure(list(
items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", "alien", "language-of-bees", 
"bad-hen"), items = c("but-how", "encyclopedia", "alien", 
"language-of-bees", "bad-hen"), people = c("Willy", "Karen", 
"Kristina", "Stefan")), .Names = c("items", "items", "people"
)))
```

I have a matrix `seloas` of 4 people x 3 rotated components, and an array `seraw` of 5 items x 5 items x (the same) 4 people.
`seraw` are raw(ish) co-occurence counts, and `seloas` are (rotated) loadings from a PCA based on that `seraw`.
The slices (= matrices) of `seraw` are symmetrical (beacuse co-occurence counts).

I now want to multiply the component loadings with *each* of the array slices, so that I get a new **4d** array of 5 items x 5 items x 4 people x 3 rotated components. 
Each person-element of the component vectors from `seloas` would be multiplied by the respective array slice `seraw` for that person.
Each cell would be the raw score of some item against some item against for some person for each of the components.
To further illustrate, I'd like

```
# res["encyclopedia", "language-of-bees", "Willy", "PC1"] ==
seloas["Willy", "PC1"] * seraw["encyclopedia", "language-of-bees", "Willy"]
```

To get the component scores as the loadings-weighted averages, I can then `apply()` my way around the 4d array, which I'd like to keep around *as is* for other summary calculations.

Is there an efficient matrix-/tensor-algebraic way of accomplishing this?

Comment: You have a better chance of getting a tested answer if you offer the output of a correct method, perhaps only the first couple of slices?

Comment: sorry, I had hoped that the second code snipped was that line ... it's just one cell though, not an entire slice.

Comment: That snippet was what I used to construct my answer. If my answer was helpful, it should be upvoted. If it fully answered the question, it should be checkmarked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an effort to clarify what Is unclear to me at the moment. Is this the desired goal? (Note that I could not figure out why the fourth dimension should be 4 if the number of principla compoents was 3)

```
res <- array(NA, c(5,5,4,3) )
dimnames(res)[[4]] <-c("PC1", "PC2" ,"PC3")
dimnames(res)[[3]] <-c("Willy", "Karen", "Kristina", "Stefan")
for( sub in c("Willy", "Karen", "Kristina", "Stefan") ) {
 for ( pc in c("PC1", "PC2" ,"PC3") ){
 res[ , ,sub, pc] <- seloas[sub, pc] * seraw[ , , sub] }}
 res[ , , "Willy", 1:2]
#---------
, , PC1

           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.2325353  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
[2,]  0.0000000 -0.23253534  0.00000000 -0.04650707 -0.04650707
[3,]  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.23253534  0.00000000 -0.04650707
[4,]  0.0000000 -0.04650707  0.00000000 -0.23253534 -0.09301414
[5,]  0.0000000 -0.04650707 -0.04650707 -0.09301414 -0.23253534

, , PC2

           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.1295918  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
[2,]  0.0000000 -0.12959177  0.00000000 -0.02591835 -0.02591835
[3,]  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.12959177  0.00000000 -0.02591835
[4,]  0.0000000 -0.02591835  0.00000000 -0.12959177 -0.05183671
[5,]  0.0000000 -0.02591835 -0.02591835 -0.05183671 -0.12959177
```

I think that you can select certain slices from the kronecker cross-product that is built this way:

```
 kres <- kronecker(seloas , seraw , make.dimnames=TRUE)
```

Notice that the "Willy:PC1" items  is the same as res[ , , "Willy", "PC1"] values

```
> kres[ 1:5, 1:5, 1]
                       PC1:but-how PC1:encyclopedia   PC1:alien PC1:language-of-bees
Willy:but-how           -0.2325353       0.00000000  0.00000000           0.00000000
Willy:encyclopedia       0.0000000      -0.23253534  0.00000000          -0.04650707
Willy:alien              0.0000000       0.00000000 -0.23253534           0.00000000
Willy:language-of-bees   0.0000000      -0.04650707  0.00000000          -0.23253534
Willy:bad-hen            0.0000000      -0.04650707 -0.04650707          -0.09301414
                       PC1:bad-hen
Willy:but-how           0.00000000
Willy:encyclopedia     -0.04650707
Willy:alien            -0.04650707
Willy:language-of-bees -0.09301414
Willy:bad-hen          -0.23253534
> res[, ,"Willy", "PC1"]
           [,1]        [,2]        [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] -0.2325353  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000
[2,]  0.0000000 -0.23253534  0.00000000 -0.04650707 -0.04650707
[3,]  0.0000000  0.00000000 -0.23253534  0.00000000 -0.04650707
[4,]  0.0000000 -0.04650707  0.00000000 -0.23253534 -0.09301414
[5,]  0.0000000 -0.04650707 -0.04650707 -0.09301414 -0.23253534
```

Not all of the items in the cross-product would be useful but this would be the "index" if you wnated to use `kronecker`:

```
> attributes(kronecker(seloas , seraw , make.dimnames=TRUE) )
$dim
[1] 20 15  4

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
 [1] "Willy:but-how"             "Willy:encyclopedia"        "Willy:alien"              
 [4] "Willy:language-of-bees"    "Willy:bad-hen"             "Karen:but-how"            
 [7] "Karen:encyclopedia"        "Karen:alien"               "Karen:language-of-bees"   
[10] "Karen:bad-hen"             "Kristina:but-how"          "Kristina:encyclopedia"    
[13] "Kristina:alien"            "Kristina:language-of-bees" "Kristina:bad-hen"         
[16] "Stefan:but-how"            "Stefan:encyclopedia"       "Stefan:alien"             
[19] "Stefan:language-of-bees"   "Stefan:bad-hen"           

$dimnames[[2]]
 [1] "PC1:but-how"          "PC1:encyclopedia"     "PC1:alien"           
 [4] "PC1:language-of-bees" "PC1:bad-hen"          "PC2:but-how"         
 [7] "PC2:encyclopedia"     "PC2:alien"            "PC2:language-of-bees"
[10] "PC2:bad-hen"          "PC3:but-how"          "PC3:encyclopedia"    
[13] "PC3:alien"            "PC3:language-of-bees" "PC3:bad-hen"         

$dimnames[[3]]
[1] ":Willy"    ":Karen"    ":Kristina" ":Stefan"
```

Comment: Absolutely. I only hesitated because I had hoped there would be proper matrix/tensor-algebraic way of doing this, which I guess is what Kronecker does, right? I went for the forloop solution which still "just" multiplies a scalar with a matrix,  I'm not even sure a matrix-y way exists, so thanks for this help.

Comment: I ended up not using Kronecker though it seems quicker, because the dim names make it hard to handle.

Comment: The `kronecker` result actually gives you more values that you wanted since ti creates "cross-person-PC" combinations as well as al the cross-items slices that is what I think you wanted, at least based on your snippet. I used it because you asked for a matrix-y solution.